# Adding geom_rug of observed values in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using the `goats` data set from the `ResourceSelection` package I can look at the relationship between `ELEVATION` and a binary response (`STATUS`) using `glm`.

```
library(ResourceSelection)
library(ggplot2)
mod <- glm(STATUS ~ ELEVATION, family=binomial, data = goats) 
summary(mod)
```

I then want to predict over a larger range of `ELEVATION`and do so with the following code.

```
df <- data.frame(ELEVATION = seq(0,5000,1))
df$Preds <- predict(mod, newdata = df, type="response")
ggplot(df, aes(x=ELEVATION, y = Preds)) + geom_point()
```

Now, with the resulting `ggplot` how can I add a rug to the bottom of the figure that shows the observed values of `ELEVATION` from the `goats` data set when `STATUS == 1`.  e.g. I want a rug showing `goats$ELEVATION[goats$STATUS == 1]`

I have tried adding `geom_rug()`, but am not sure how to include the values from the `goats` data frame rather than the `df` that I used in the `ggplot` code.  In other words, how can I include a rug of the observed values (subset as indicated above) from the original data in the plot with the new predicted data from the `df` data frame?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried? A good start would be `+ geom_rug()`. That will, of course, add all the points. You can subset your data down to only plot some of the points.

Comment: @Gregor I have added clarification and more details in the OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`geom_rug` has a data argument (all geoms do), so you should just give it that data you want to be plotted.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=ELEVATION, y = Preds)) + geom_point() +
    geom_rug(data = subset(goats, STATUS == 1),
             aes(x = ELEVATION), inherit.aes = F)
```

In this case, you map `y = Preds`, which is a column not present in the `goats` data, so we need to set `inherit.aes = F` for the rug layer using the goats data to prevent ggplot from looking for the nonexistent column.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info on `inherit.aes = F`. Very helpful.